# Adding icon in electron app throw Error: spawn UNKNOWN

Tags: electron, nsis, electron-builder

electron-builder.yml

```
appId: com
productName: ABC

asar: false

directories:
  buildResources: dist-assets/
  output: dist/

files:
  - package.json
  - init.js
  - build/
  - node_modules/

win:
  target: nsis
  # icon: "app/client/assets/images/icon.ico"
```

when I build code using the above file it works fine and creates exe and NSIS installer

but if I uncomment the icon line then it creates an exe file but on building, NSIS throws below error (error on building target=nsis)

```
• writing effective config  file=dist\builder-effective-config.yaml
  • rebuilding native dependencies  dependencies=better-sqlite3@7.5.0 platform=win32 arch=x64
  • install prebuilt binary  name=better-sqlite3 version=7.5.0 platform=win32 arch=x64 napi=
  • packaging       platform=win32 arch=x64 electron=15.3.5 appOutDir=dist\win-unpacked
  • building        target=nsis file=dist\ABC Setup 1.0.0.exe archs=x64 oneClick=true perMachine=false  
[15:52:45] 'builder-win' errored after 1.98 min
[15:52:45] Error: spawn UNKNOWN
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:403:11)
    at spawn (child_process.js:580:9)
    at Object.execFile (child_process.js:248:17)
    at C:\Users\hp\Desktop\PROJECT\GitHub\ABC\node_modules\builder-util\src\util.ts:94:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.exec (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\PROJECT\GitHub\ABC\node_modules\builder-util\src\util.ts:93:10)
    at Object.execWine (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\PROJECT\GitHub\ABC\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\wine.ts:11:12)
    at NsisTarget.computeScriptAndSignUninstaller (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\PROJECT\GitHub\ABC\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\targets\nsis\NsisTarget.ts:387:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at NsisTarget.buildInstaller (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\PROJECT\GitHub\ABC\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\targets\nsis\NsisTarget.ts:306:9)
    at NsisTarget.finishBuild (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\PROJECT\GitHub\ABC\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\targets\nsis\NsisTarget.ts:131:9)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at AsyncTaskManager.awaitTasks (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\PROJECT\GitHub\ABC\node_modules\builder-util\src\asyncTaskManager.ts:65:25)
    at Packager.doBuild (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\PROJECT\GitHub\ABC\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\packager.ts:453:5)
    at Object.executeFinally (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\PROJECT\GitHub\ABC\node_modules\builder-util\src\promise.ts:12:14)
    at Packager._build (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\PROJECT\GitHub\ABC\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\packager.ts:376:31)
```

icon 256X256, 10.1kb

does this cause by an icon?

if so what should I have checked for the icon?

if not what can cause this error?

Thank you.

Comment: If you believe this is a NSIS problem then the error message from makensis would be nice. Can you upload the icon somewhere so we can inspect it?

Comment: ya, it is an icon problem I created an icon again from the same image then tried again to build and it does not throw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I had this error once, the simple fix is replacing the icon as the one I had was somehow corrupted.
Just re-create the .ico icon and add it.

Funny how things break on their own and it's not your fault.